# Как в JS передавать значения не по ID а по name?

Tags: javascript, ajax

Есть рабочий код но мне необходимо чтобы он связывался не чрез  ID (#testSelect) а через name="testSelect-name". Возможно ли это? Или это костыли?

```js
$("#testSelect").change(function(e) {
  $("#title-place").text($(this.options[this.selectedIndex]).text());
}).change();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="testSelect" name="testSelect-name">
  <option>One</option>
  <option>Two</option>
  <option>Three</option>
</select>
<br/><br/>
<span id="title-place">Empty</span>
```

Comment: Как то так `$('[name="testSelect-name"]')`

Comment: http://jquery.page2page.ru/index.php5/%D0%A1%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%8B подробнее по jquery и селекторы тут

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`document.querySelector('[name=testSelect-name]');`

Стандартная библиотека JavaScript позволяет это делать так.
Аналогично в JQuery.